# Change meta tags dynamically angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, meta-tags

I'm trying to change the `content` of the meta tag `Keyword` dynamically.

I have :

```
<meta name="keywords" content="">
```

and I am making as follows:

```
$("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content", "hello");
```

I put on a display in the meta keywords and saw that was setted the hello , but when I go to view source code I see that the content is still blank.

It has a way around this problem ?

**EDIT: 
I will not use it anymore. I managed to get around the need and include this meta tag by PHP. Thank you for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

View source code only shows the content that was originally downloaded.  It does not show dynamic changes you have made via Javascript.  If you want to see those, you can look in the DOM Inspector and see the current DOM hierarchy.

FYI, since `<meta>` tags are typically for the benefit of crawlers (such as search engines) and many search engines do not execute your Javacscript, you might think twice about whether changing your `<meta>` tags with Javascript is actually accomplishing anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

There would be no benefit to this because search engines crawl static pages which are indexed.

If you for some reason have to do this, you can give that meta tag an id and do something like this with jQuery:

```
<meta name="keywords" id="keywords" content="">
$('#keywords').attr('content', 'hello!');
```

Comment: Still the problem. The value is assigned , but when I look at the source code it is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

You will only see the changes in the developer tools panel, this is the concept of SPA, angular will not change the code of the html file, only at JS running instance. To make it functional to your website you will need to use a preprocessor at your web server.

Comment: I will not use it anymore. I managed to get around the need and include this meta tag by PHP. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, please don't forget to vote in my answer. Thanks.